# Conflict between Yoast SEO and my custom theme

Tags: customization, templates, seo, debug

I’ve been developping custom themes for not so long, so it is the first time I have a conflict between my theme and a plugin and I'm not really sure how to debug this exactly and fix it.

When my custom theme and Yoast SEO plugin are both activated, there are some issue running the back-end side of my WP (The front-end is totally fine). When I open a page to edit it, and some of my ACF fields appear not filled and I can't click any of the Yoast options to edit them either, clicking does nothing. It also does not seem to let me show/hide the sections of the post edit page.

Even when I go in the Yoast SEO settings, I can't edit theme in this situation.

I’ve troubleshoot all plugins with Troubleshoot Mode from the Health Check plugin and tried different themes and my error only occurs when my custom theme (child theme of “blankslate theme”) is activated and that Yoast SEO is activated too.

I’m not sure how to debug this, I’d like help to figure out which steps I should take to debug my theme.

Running PHP 7.1 on an apache server.
WP 5.3.2 and all plugins are updated to last versions.

Plugins currently installed:

- ACF Pro
- ACF: Image Crop Add-on
- Classic Editor
- Health Check & Troubleshooting
- reSmush.it Image Optimizer
- UpdraftPlus
- WP Fastest Cache
- Yoast SEO

The theme is one I developped using a child theme from "BlankSlate" theme as parent.

[Image of Javascript errors reported on the console](https://pasteboard.co/IXJv8nR.png)

Comment: Can you clarify the exact problem?  The background info is helpful, explaining how you determined which plugin was causing the conflict with your theme, but the problem you are attempting to solve is not clear.

Comment: Like I said, the back-end is not running well. When I open the "Search Appearance" page from Yoast SEO, all the settings are not clickable. They're not  grayed-out, its just that nothing is happening.

And I'm using ACF Pro to make some custom fields, and it appears to be altering the well-being of this plugin too by making some text not appear in those fields + some tabs not appearing. (Tabs created by ACF)

And these little arrows (https://ibb.co/9hr4fvB) are not working either, making me suspect something not working.

I re-installed the WP core as well as the Yoast plugin. No success

Comment: Sounds like JS conflicts.  Have you examined the console to verify problems there? Scanning the web it appears there is a history of Yoast and ACF conflicts.

Comment: Yes, I provided a screenshot of the console errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem, was actually not even a plugin conflict but an optimisation operation that had broke the plugins!

I added a couple days ago a script in functions.php that would "defer" all the scripts, which made important scripts being loaded after they were being executed.

Thanks for the help.